# Can `benchmark overhead` support `pre-runtime digests`?

Tags: benchmark, digest, inherent

Our runtime uses an inherent which itself requires a pre-runtime digest to be present. I don't believe this is supported; from what I can tell, the benchmarking only handles the `inherents` provided by the implementation:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/utils/frame/benchmarking-cli/src/extrinsic/bench.rs#L130

Specifically, we use `author-inherent` from `Nimbus`: https://github.com/PureStake/nimbus/blob/0e5702105941baba0e08b343ceaa217192191b73/pallets/author-inherent/src/lib.rs

Which follows this workflow:

- `on_initialize()` must be called with a certain `pre_runtime_digest` present. This is copied into a storage item.
- The `kickoff_authorship_validation` inherent must then be called, which then expects this storage item to be present.

Without the ability to inject this pre-runtime digest, `benchmark overhead` is triggering a failure in this inherent because `on_initialize` failed to find the injected digest into pallet storage.

Comment: Uh, interesting... I will have to look into this in-depth to see what's possible. DQ but could you add another inherent that executes before and inserts this pre-digest? Not ideal though. Do you have the code available?

Comment: That could be a viable workaround. Currently I hacked up a version of nimbus to get around the panic, but that's obviously less than ideal.

Code can be found in this PR (without my cargo overrides, etc.): https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/pull/1490